# new_transformation not working with multiple inputs from tsibble object inside ARIMA

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, fable-r

I am working on exercise #4 from this book.

https://otexts.com/fpp3/dynamic-exercises.html

I am trying to create a transformation to adjust for CPI, however, it appears because I am passing two variables from the tsibble object into my transformation function, it does not recognize it as a transformation of the data, but rather as a new data series. Any idea how to correct?

```
library(fpp3)

cpi_adj <- function(data, cpi) {
  return(data/cpi*100)
}

cpi_unadj <- function(data, cpi) {
  return(data*cpi/100)
}

cpi_trans <- new_transformation(cpi_adj, cpi_unadj)

aus_acc_fit <- aus_accommodation %>% 
  model(ARIMA(cpi_trans(Takings, CPI) ~ trend(knots = yearquarter("2008 Q1")) + season()))

aus_acc_fit %>% 
  filter(State == "Victoria") %>%
  report()
```

This is the output I get and you can see in the header of the model summary, rather than recognizing it as a transformation, it recognizes it as a new data series instead.

```
Series: cpi_trans(Takings, CPI) 
Model: LM w/ ARIMA(1,0,0)(0,0,1)[4] errors 

Coefficients:
         ar1    sma1  trend(knots = yearquarter("2008 Q1"))trend  trend(knots = yearquarter("2008 Q1"))trend_41  season()year2  season()year3  season()year4  intercept
      0.6596  0.3756                                      3.1995                                         0.3892       -57.8760       -36.0249       -12.9360   264.4398
s.e.  0.0866  0.1242                                      0.4871                                         0.9790         3.9693         4.6151         4.0447    13.3769

sigma^2 estimated as 170.8:  log likelihood=-291.63
AIC=601.26   AICc=604.07   BIC=622
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{fable}` will attempt to identify the response variable from your left hand side based on the length of the variables. Since both `Takings` and `CPI` have the same variable length, it cannot distinguish if you were trying to forecast `Takings` or `CPI` - so it instead forecasts `cpi_trans(Takings, CPI)`.

To explicitly define which variable is the response, you can use the `resp()` function.

Also note that for simpler transformations like yours, it is possible to directly write the transformation on the left side of the formula. For example: `ARIMA(resp(Takings)/CPI*100 ~ trend(knots = yearquarter("2008 Q1")) + season())`

```r
library(fpp3)
cpi_adj <- function(data, cpi) {
  return(data/cpi*100)
}

cpi_unadj <- function(data, cpi) {
  return(data*cpi/100)
}

cpi_trans <- new_transformation(cpi_adj, cpi_unadj)

aus_acc_fit <- aus_accommodation %>% 
  model(ARIMA(cpi_trans(resp(Takings), CPI) ~ trend(knots = yearquarter("2008 Q1")) + season()))

aus_acc_fit %>% 
  filter(State == "Victoria") %>%
  report()
#> Series: Takings 
#> Model: LM w/ ARIMA(1,0,0)(0,0,1)[4] errors 
#> Transformation: cpi_trans(Takings, CPI) 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>          ar1    sma1  trend(knots = yearquarter("2008 Q1"))trend
#>       0.6596  0.3756                                      3.1995
#> s.e.  0.0866  0.1242                                      0.4871
#>       trend(knots = yearquarter("2008 Q1"))trend_41  season()year2
#>                                              0.3892       -57.8760
#> s.e.                                         0.9790         3.9693
#>       season()year3  season()year4  intercept
#>            -36.0249       -12.9360   264.4398
#> s.e.         4.6151         4.0447    13.3769
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 170.8:  log likelihood=-291.63
#> AIC=601.26   AICc=604.07   BIC=622
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Mitchell that is brilliant, thank you!! I was looking for that type of solution, just couldn't find that darn `resp()` function. Much appreciated!!